# How to use scope_identity in jdbc

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc, primary-key, scope-identity

How to use `scope_identity` in JDBC?
I have to insert one table (which is in SQL Server ) primary key value into another table which is using  first table primary key as foreign key.

Comment: Actually , I want to retrieve primary key value from one table and want to insert it into another table

Comment: You shouldn't use scope_identity in JDBC, you should use the generated keys facility (which below the covers may or may not use scope_identity).

Comment: From that , I'm getting error , please see to the below code